# json array for events array in jQuery fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, fullcalendar

i'm using jQuery fullcalendar and i must set events dynamically, from a query, using a JSON array, for now i'm trying with a static array.
This is my code:

```
<?php 
        $arr = array(
            array(
                "title" => "first",
                "start" => "2016-10-18T10:00",
                "end" => "2016-10-18T11:00"
            ),
            array(
                "title" => "second",
                "start" => "2016-10-18T12:00",
                "end" => "2016-10-18T13:00"
            ),
            array(
                "title" => "third",
                "start" => "2016-10-18T16:00",
                "end" => "2016-10-18T17:00"
            )
        );

        json_encode($arr);
    ?>

$(document).ready(function () {
        var initialLocaleCode = 'it';
        var events = [$arr];
        var eventsArray = [];
        console.log('e',events);
        $.parseJSON(events).forEach(function(element, index){
            eventsArray.push({
                title:element.title,
                description:element.description.substring(0,30),
                start:new Date(element.start).toISOString(),
                end:new Date(element.end).toISOString(),
         })
        }
    }

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
            locale: initialLocaleCode,
            buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
            weekNumbers: true,
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: eventsArray;
```

it doesn't work... Can someone help me?
Thank's

Comment: Can you check if you have an error in your console on your web browser? I guess the semi-colon at the end is just a syntax error when you copied your code here.

Comment: And `var events = [$arr];`. You mix Javascript/PHP

Comment: i have an error in console, this: Unexpected token )

Comment: can you help me??

Comment: You should have the error line in your console. I'm pretty sure you can find by yourself. You didn't confirm that you made a typo in your code. `fullCalendar{(` is closed ? (`)};`)

Comment: the console tell me thath the error is in the line under "end: new Date ().... "

Comment: No "description" in the events array $arr. Revisit your code.

Comment: thank's but the error remained

Comment: try events = $arr instead of  events = [$arr] because $arr is already an array...

Comment: the error doesn't change...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your code. Try below one.

```
<?php 
        $arr = array(
            array(
                "title" => "first",
                "start" => "2016-10-18T10:00",
                "end" => "2016-10-18T11:00"
            ),
            array(
                "title" => "second",
                "start" => "2016-10-18T12:00",
                "end" => "2016-10-18T13:00"
            ),
            array(
                "title" => "third",
                "start" => "2016-10-18T16:00",
                "end" => "2016-10-18T17:00"
            )
        );

        $jsonArr = json_encode($arr);
    ?>

$(document).ready(function () {
        var initialLocaleCode = 'it';
        var events = <?php echo $jsonArr; ?>;
        var eventsArray = [];
        console.log('e',events);
        $.parseJSON(events).forEach(function(element, index){
            eventsArray.push({
                title:element.title,
                description:element.description.substring(0,30),
                start:new Date(element.start).toISOString(),
                end:new Date(element.end).toISOString(),
         })
        }
    }

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
            locale: initialLocaleCode,
            buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
            weekNumbers: true,
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: eventsArray;
```

Hope, this will work..!!!

Comment: the console tell me: Unexpected token < in this line "var events = <?php= $arr ?>"

Comment: now the error is: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in the jquery.min.js file

Comment: either use ```<?= $arr ?>``` or ```<?php echo $arr; ?>```

Comment: Try this var events = '<?php echo $jsonArr; ?>';  or  var events = ['<?php echo $jsonArr; ?>'];